# Problema com Retorno de função, mesmo retornando falso executa

Tags: javascript, angular, funções

Olha só, tenho um código onde a pessoa digita o CPF dela, verifica se o usuário existe ou não, se sim, busca os dados dele, verifica se ele possui senha ou não, se possui vai para uma página se não possui vai para outra.

Qual é o problema?

Tenho esse código:

```js
async validacao(usuario) {
      if (this.usuarioExiste(usuario)) {
          this.receberUsuario(usuario);
          this.authLoginService.senhaExiste(usuario);

      } else {
          console.log('Não encontrado');
      }
  }

  async usuarioExiste(usuario) {
      await this.http
          .get<UsuarioDados>(environment.url + 'Metodo=alunoCheckCPF&AlunoCPF=' + usuario.cpf)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => {
              usuario.numero_registros = response.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.Registros;
          });

      if (usuario.numero_registros === 1) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  async receberUsuario(usuario) {
      await this.http
        .get<UsuarioDados>(environment.url + 'Metodo=alunoCheckCPF&AlunoCPF=' + usuario.cpf)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res1 => {
            usuario.nome = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].nome_aluno;
            usuario.id = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].id_aluno_main;
            usuario.idNaAcademia = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].id_aluno_academia;
            usuario.senha = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].aluno_senha;
            usuario.nomeAcademia = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].academia_nome;
            usuario.idAcademia = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].id_academia;
        });
      await this.http
          .get<UsuarioContatos>(
              environment.url + 'Metodo=alunoLoginContatos&AlunoIDMain=' + usuario.id + '&CttoValidacao=true'
          )
          .toPromise()
          .then(res2 => {
              usuario.celular = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos[0].Contato;
              usuario.email = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos[1].Contato;

          });

      this.armazenarUsuario(usuario);
  }
```

A ideia é que se o número de registros do usuário for 1, ou seja, o usuário existe, retorna true, se for 0, ele não existe, então retorna false.

A função `validacao()` verifica o retorno da função `usuarioExiste()` era suposto se retornasse true, executasse as duas outras funções `receberUsuario()` e `senhaExiste()`, se retornasse false, dar um `console.log('Não encontrado')`, então peguei 2 CPF's, um válido e outro não.

O Válido executa perfeitamente, recebe o usuário, verifica se tem senha, redireciona para a página, tudo uma maravilha, já o inválido não.

O inválido mesmo a função `usuarioExiste()` estar retornando false, a função `validacao()` está permitindo que ele execute a `receberUsuario()` e eu não sei bem o porquê, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O problema é que o método `usuarioExiste` é `async`, então não tem como ele retornar um `boolean`, ele irá retornar uma `Promise<boolean>`. Você precisa tratar esse retorno, utilizando `await` por exemplo pegar o valor dessa promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `usuarioExiste` é asincrona, ou seja, seu retorno não é um `boolean`, mas sim uma `Promise<boolean>`, então você precisa esperar a promessa ser comprida para então fazer a verificação, você pode fazer isso com o `then`, porém a forma mais simples é com `async` e `await`

Na sua chamada a função dentro da condição troque por:

```
if (await this.usuarioExiste(usuario)) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito. Muito obrigado!